# Getting data out of Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

We've set up a method of updating data in Marketing Cloud (keeping it as up to date as possible via transfers every 15 mins). I want to start getting the Data View stuff out with the same kind of frequency - any ideas?

It looks like the dataextract activities can only be run every hour (and with a rolling 1 day time span meaning a bunch of duplication) has anyone found or can anyone think of a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options:

1. setup 4 automations to run data extract activities and scheduled them to run hourly at 15 minute intervals.
2. consider retrieving data via API and using external service to schedule requests (e.g. every 15 minutes).
3. trigger automation externally - following is example of how to make request https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md

Comment: Thank for this.  
1. I'm guessing this would not just give me changes every 15 mins? it'd be a lot of duplicated records? As far as I can see the date view stuff (sends, opens etc) don't seem to have a primary key.  
  
2. Do you mean using something like [this] (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-data-from-a-data-extension.html). Is there any limit to the amount of data I can get in one go?  
Thanks again

Comment: If you would like only changes then use a query to filter and then extract result from query.

Refer to following https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-data-from-a-data-extension.html for example of RetrieveRequest - note that you will need to page through results will more than one soap request for greater than 2,500 records.

Other third option is to trigger automation externally - following is example of how to make request https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md